# Upload photo from SD to Firebase Storage without all path

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I want to upload a photo to `FirebaseStorage`, taking it from my device. If the photo resides on the device it creates it under the folder `/Photos/namefile.jpg` while if I load from the SD card it gives me all the path `/Photos/storage/emulated/0/namefile.jpg`. I would like to save the data all with `/Photos/namefile.jpg`

This is my code:

```
    if (requestCode==GALERY_INTENT &&resultCode==RESULT_OK){
        final Uri uri = data.getData();
        Log.d(TAG,uri.getLastPathSegment().toString());
        Log.d(TAG,uri.toString());
        StorageReference path = storeRef.child(uid).child("Photos").child(uri.getLastPathSegment());
        path.putFile(uri).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) {
                if(task.isSuccessful()){

                   //file uploaded

                }

            }


        });
```

UPDATE

Now it is working well with the folowing code:

```
final Uri uri = data.getData();
            File file = new File(uri+"");            
            String [] segments = file.getName().split("[\\p{Punct}‘]2F");
            StorageReference path = storeRef.child(uid).child("Photos").child(segments[segments.length-1]);
```

Comment: /Photos/filename.jpg is the path I want to create in Firebase Storage.

Comment: That is certainly an unexpected behavior. But please try casting that Uri to File `File file  = new File(uri+"");` and then pass the file name to the path: `StorageReference path = storeRef.child(uid).child("Photos").child(file.getName());`

Comment: Now the file is saved in the path I want with the name "% 2Fstorage% 2Femulated% 2F0% 2FDCIM% 2FCamera% 2FIMG_20180114_162053.jpg". At least now it does not create as many nodes in the db as there are folders of the name. Thank you.

Comment: I might have a workaround for that. I'll post it as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can cast that Uri to File:

```
File file = new File(uri+"");
```

Then get the file name from the path and pass it to the storageReference:

```
String [] segments = file.getName().split();
StorageReference path = storeRef.child(uid).child("Photos").child(segments[segments.length-1]);
```